How do I loop in python and dynamically create instances of objects that may require different arguments?
I have various subclasses of statistical models in my repo that typically take similar arguments but some may require special arguments. I'm writing a function to create, train, and score each model and then compare their accuracy. That leads to two linked questions:

What is the best data structure to use to loop through models; and
How would I pass the specific special arguments if/when they occur? I think this is a case for kwargs but am still fairly new to implementing kwargs.

My current planned architecture is:
def compare_models(dataframe, models):
    results = {}
    for model in models:
        x = ModelClass() #need to select the right model class based on the 
                          #item in models
        x.train(dataframe, <any special arguments>)
        results.update({model: [<x attributes>]})
     
    return results


Sometimes the best configuration language is python itself. Instead of a for loop, you could write out specific model.train(...) calls.

zip models with separate iterable(s) of the special arguments and/or attributes?

@tdelaney, I don't follow. The problem is I don't know in advance which models may be compared, as the model subclasses in our library are regularly evolving/expanding

@ShadowRanger, can you elaborate on that or provide sample code? Am I making  models a tuple and iterating through a tuple?

Are you asking how to initialize the model instances, or are you asking how to call the train() function on each instance?  Or both?

What is models in your example?  Is it a list of model classes, or model instances, or something else?

@JohnGordon, good point. Models should just contain instructions to create the instances. I updated question slightly to show that whatever models is, it would contain the class as well. If it was a list of nested dictionaries, it might be like {'regression1': {'modelclass': LinearModel, 'args':[...]}

If I understand correctly, the way this is usually done in python is to put your args in a dictionary (i.e. kwargs = {"arg1": value1 ...} then pass as x.train(dataframe, **kwargs). kwargs stands for keyword arguments and is a way of passing arguments by name.

How does compare_models know what arguments need to be passed to each .train call? You could pass the arguments as a list/tuple or dictionary and use argument unpacking

@DavidWaterworth, thanks. That is kind of what I expected. I guess if I'm going to have a lot of nested dictionaries, it might be easiest to make a dataframe where the columns are model_name, model_class, kwargs and iterate over/apply against the dataframe?

Yeah or dict of dicts, where the first level dict contains one entry per model, and the sub-dicts are the kwargs.

To accompany each model with specialized keyword arguments when passing a collection of models as an argument to a function, the most natural data structure for the models would be an iterable of tuple of model and kwargs so that the function can iteratively unpack each model with its accompanying kwargs:
from typing import Iterable, Any

def compare_models(dataframe: DataFrame, models: Iterable[tuple[Model, dict[str, Any]]):
    results = {}
    for model, kwargs in models:
        x = model()
        x.train(dataframe, **kwargs)
        results.update({model: vars(x)})
    return results

so you can call it with something like:
compare_models(df, [
    (Model1, dict(foo='Foo', bar=1)),
    (Model2, dict()),
    (Model3, dict(baz='Baz'))
])


Thanks for the answer and comment from @David Waterworth. I used a mix of both suggestions. I used a dictionary of dictionaries where the second level had the model type for creating the instance and optionally contained kwargs. My loop took the form proposed above. Note, I needed to create each instance using model = globals()value['modeltype']
